# Using python CSV to find Average of each student, male and female average and highest student average

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, csv

Every time I run this code only one row of code prints and I can't get the average to match with what's it's supposed to.
Here's the Excel file I have to go through.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVK4r.jpg)

```
import csv

average = 0 
sum = 0
row_count = 0
M = 0
F = 0

with open ("C:\\Users\\jayle\\Downloads\\Grades.csv", "r") as gradebook:
    reader = csv.reader(gradebook, delimiter=",")
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        Student = row [0]
        Gender = row [1]
        Grades = row [2:]

        for Grades in reader:
            for column in row [2:]:
                n=float(column)
            sum += n
        row_count += 1
    average = sum / len(column) / 5
    print (Student, 'average is:', average)
    for Gender in reader:
        print (row [1])
        if row [1] == Gender:
            M += average)
        else:
            F += 1, (average)
    print ("Male Average is ", average)
    print ("Female Average is ", average)
```

Comment: CSV file is not an Excel file ... viewing it in Excel does not make it one

Comment: what do you mean by `one row of code prints`?

Comment: Student A average is: 81.0  Male Average is  81.0 Female Average is  81.0 this is all i get with the code I currently have. @jsotola

Comment: insert a bunch of `print` statements to find out what the program is doing exactly... determine if `for row in reader:` block repeats for each row in the table

Comment: Ok, whenever I do just print(Student) it outputs just Student A instead of Students A-J and when I do Gender it just outputs male and when I print Grades it outputs the whole Row for Student J @jsotola

Comment: reduce the code to just print each row ... make sure that it is iterating through the whole csv file

Comment: Ok I took off all the extra code after Grades= row[2:] now whenever I do a print statement it outputs each row I'm doing the print statements inside of the for loop @jsotola